# Residence cancelled in EU, validity of drivers license issued in one of EU state?

Tags: driving-licenses

I moved out of EU with valid drivers license (issued in EU member state - Denmark ) to another non EU country, is it still possible to drive with that drivers license back in EU (Hungary, Austria, Germany, etc.)  as tourist ? I live in country which has lot of people living and working in EU, traffic police here is mostly concerned that locals drive  say -  car with German plates, and I never bothered to change my drivers license :) What is my legal position  if I drive my car with that aforementioned drivers license in EU?

Best regards,

Comment: The law controlling this will depend on which country you're driving in and on which country issued your license.  Can you specify?

Comment: My license is issued in Denmark,  driving area will be - say, Hungary, Austria, Germany.

Comment: [Edit] that into your question please; questions should contain **all** relevant info, because comments can disappear

Comment: @J.Doe This seems to indicate that you can drive elsewhere in the EU, providing your licence remains valid https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/driving-licence/driving-licence-recognition-validity/index_en.htm

Comment: Thank you, I had same conclusion, but, it is better to ask in order to clear any doubt  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can keep driving with your driving license after you leave your country of residence, assuming that the country where you want to drive recognizes the license.

All EU countries recognize all EU licenses so you are good there.

More information and confirmation of the rules on [this site.](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/driving-licence/driving-licence-recognition-validity/index_en.htm)

> If your driving licence is issued by an EU country, it's **recognised throughout the EU.**

Emphasis on the site.